# In bootstrap 4 how nav menu appear push and overly from Right to Left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Help me regarding this issue i build up website on bootstrap 4 but need on mobile or tablet view nav menu should appear right to left instead of top to bottom. That should be pushy and overly.

Any body can help?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: You need to start showing more own effort, instead of asking these “how can I” or “I need, you show me how” questions. Please go read [ask].